# Change Div element after succes ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh, reload

I've already searched on stack but i can't find anything.

I have a page.php

in this page there is a form

```js
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#submit').click(function(){     
    var name = $('.myname').val();
    var data = 'myname='+name;
    $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"welcome.php",
     data:data,
     success: function (html){        
      $('.myname').val(''),
      $('#message').html(html),
      $('#resultat').show();     
  
     }
  
    });
    return false;
   });
 });
</script>
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>  
<form>
<label>Enter your Name</label>
<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" class="uname"/> <br/>
<input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="resultat"> 
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none display" id="menuTable" >
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Rub</th>
   <th>Publish</th>
   <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
   </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><?php $result['rub'] ?></td>
    <td><?php $result['id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php $result['id'] ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

I would like to update the div #resultat with the new table from database.  but i can't.

I' don't want to load a external file, but only refresh the div # resultat.

Thanks

Comment: What is getting returned for `html` when you look under the network panel of dev tools? And can you show us the relevant php in welcome.php?

Comment: Also, "but i can't." is kind of vague. What happens with your current code? Does it not update anything, does it update but not with the information you expect? Try to be more specific

Comment: HI thanks for response. I wait for in the email, but i don't see you answer me.

Comment: Hello, i don't see the answer.

Comment: I have this in my  welcome. page.<?php require(MYSQL);
if(!empty($_POST['uname'])){
$name = trim($_POST['uname']);

 // Add the product to the database:
  $q = 'INSERT INTO rubPhoto (nom) VALUES (?)';
   // Prepare the statement:
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's',  $name);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) === 1) { 
     
      echo '<h4>Rubrique <strong>'.$name.'</strong> Add!</h4>';
   
     }else{
      echo ' Error';
     }
}else{
 echo'Empty field ';
}?>

Comment: My big trouble is to refresh the div when i come to add a new name.  i want to see the list with the new name added.  Thanks